# Can it be the wrong type of data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-length

Here's how the string comes to existence:

```
presidentsname = ((lista[number]).split("|")).slice(0,1);
document.diagnostic.window1.value=presidentsname+"    " +presidentsname.length;
```

with Hollande the name shows properly, but the length turns out to be 1

how to modify presidentsname.length in order to obtain 8?

or must the error be elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presidentsname` is in this case an array with one element

you can put a line between the two:

```
presidentsname = presidentsname[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are getting the length of the array and not the length of the String.